# create transpose table with each group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Current format:

```
sample = {'Store': [1,1,2], 'Product': ['a','b','a'],'Region':[1,1,1],'w0_sales':[34,32,44],'w1_sales':[23,22,33],'w2_sales':[12,33,49]}
sample = pd.DataFrame(data = sample)
sample
```

Desired format:

```
modified = {'Store': [1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2], 'Product': ['a','a','a','b','b','b','a','a','a'],'Region':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],'weeks':[0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2],'sales':[34,23,12,32,22,33,44,33,49]}
modified = pd.DataFrame(data = modified)
modified
```

I need some helps to modify the data frame to the desired format. Since the current format is the output of the model, it is hard to change.  Any suggestions? Please advise. Big thanks!

Comment: Please do not use images: paste your sample dataframe; however, it looks like you should use [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.melt.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using  [`pd.melt()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.melt.html) :

```
pd.melt(df,id_vars=['Store','Material','Dist_Chan'],var_name='week',value_name='Sales')
```